# Can't go to linked page when clicking on picture

Tags: html, css

I would like to be redirected to Google when I click on a picture but it doesnt work. I used `<a href="https://www.google.com">` but somehow the it doesnt recognize it. Do you know what the problem is and how to solve it?

HTML

```
<div class="image-parent">
  <div data-content="Go to google" class="image fit">
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/abstract-orange-linking-dots-background-600w-334647518.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image:after, .image:before {
            position:absolute;
            opacity:0;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        }
        .image:after {
            content:'\A';
            width:100%; height:100%;
            top:0; left:0;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        }
        .image:before {
            content: attr(data-content);
            width:100%;
            color:#fff;
            z-index:1;
            padding:30px 30px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            text-align:center;
            background:red;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
            opacity:1;
        }
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/5arxwq3k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Fiddle, The `<a>` tag is above the div: https://jsfiddle.net/bardalesj/xoLzdem9/

Comment: Thank you. Your solution was the fastest

Answer (score 1):

Simply dont put the :after and the :before on the .image class because the one is on your div-element outside the -tag.

put it on the a-tag or the image tag like

```
.image a:before
```

The way you have it right now it only extends the styled click area of the div tag which is not part of the link

Do same with the :hover rules and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your html and add an onclick listener.

```
<div class="image-parent">
  <div data-content="Go to google" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com')" class="image fit">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/abstract-orange-linking-dots-background-600w-334647518.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution is an alternative to using a link.

Comment: Or you could always move the ```<a>``` tag above the div.